Too long TBB's shedule time when using parallel_deterministic_reduce
Followed Scheduling Overhead in an Intel® oneAPI Threading Building Blocks Application. I write a program: test_tbb_perf_vtune_profiler
And test the program using Intel VTune Profiler:

The call stack for arena_slot::get_task and TBB Schedule Internals:


When I try to change to use tbb::task_arena ta(8);, there's no significant performance change:
double VectorReduction(double* v, size_t n) {
  tbb::task_arena ta(8);
  double sum = ta.execute([&]() {
    return tbb::parallel_deterministic_reduce(
      tbb::blocked_range<double*>(v, v + n), 0.0,
      [](const tbb::blocked_range<double*>& r, double value) -> double { return std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), value); },
      std::plus<double>());
  });

  return sum;
}

My question is: does any way to reduce schedule time of Intel::TBB?

I guess it's because size of a task is too small. Rule of thumb: each task should be at least 10'000 clocks. Maybe you can try to make a task bigger: tbb::blocker_range<doble*>(v, v+n, 5000/elements/)
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onetbb/developer-guide-api-reference/2021-9/reduction.html
4th from bottom block code

Thanks @ntfs.hard, the measured time decrease to about 117 seconds (origin is more than 180 seconds.)  when change grain size to 10000.

I consider it will create a thread-pool when Intel TBB initialized. But from the result from VTune Profiler, it seems will call pthread_create for each user task. Does my guess correct ? (I'm confused why there's so long time for thread creation / shedule for a HPC toolset)

AFAIR threads will are created when they need it, it will be wasteful to create whole treads on init. You can try to warm-up library with 2 parallel loops. Second one shouldn't have a tread creation overhead

Thanks for your explain. I forgot to post the test result after change grain size.
After explicitly set grain size to 10, 000, or use static partitioner, the run time down to about 2 ~ 3 seconds.
